# On a Xamarin Forms Platform renderer, when should I call base.OnElementChanged(e) base.OnElementPropertyChanged(e)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Xamarin University has the following code.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using XFDraw;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using XFDraw.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SketchView), typeof(SketchViewRenderer))]
namespace XFDraw.iOS
{
    class SketchViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<SketchView, PaintView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SketchView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var paintView = new PaintView();
                paintView.SetInkColor(this.Element.InkColor.ToUIColor());
                SetNativeControl(paintView);
            }


          // move the base call to here??
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == SketchView.InkColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                Control.SetInkColor(Element.InkColor.ToUIColor());
            }

          // move the base call to here??
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that if I want to create a **reusable control with overridable platform specifics** I need to move the base call to the last action in each method.

Answer (score 2):

You should generally be calling it first, the idea being that you want your changes to override anything the base is doing.